# Adding scanf makes processInputStream in Java disappear

Tags: java, c, io, pipe

I tried to run a C program inside Java one and Java one is supposed to get `stdin`/`stadout` of my C program. The moment I add `scanf` to C code, C doesn't seem to see Java's output.

When I make only `printf`s in C and tell Java to `readLine`, it works. the moment I add in Java write to process but not yet `scanf`s in C, it also works, just C ignores output of Java. The moment I add `scanf` after `printf` (and I can make before `printf sleep()`, put several `printf()`s in row, etc.) I can no longer see `printf()`'s effect inside Java although it is executed first.

`fflush()` in C works to allow Java to see `printf()`, but C still can't see writes of Java. Also tried `writer.flush();` and multiple writes in Java with no effect to be seen. And also tried to run Process via ProcessBuilder with no difference at all.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

 Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Project9.exe");

InputStream processInputStream = process.getInputStream();
OutputStream processOutputStream = process.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(processOutputStream));
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(processInputStream));
String val;
int n=0;
while(true){

    while((val=reader.readLine())!=null){
    System.out.println(val);
    }
    writer.write(n);
    writer.newLine();
    n++;
}
```

And C program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int n=0;
    while (1) {
        printf("test %d\n", n);
        printf("test %d\n", n);
        printf("test %d\n", n);
        printf("test %d\n",n);
        fflush(stdout); //(1)
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }
return;
}
```

With `fflush` and `scanf` commented, the programs properly loop. With `scanf` but without `fflush` even `printf`s doesn't appear in output although they are executed first. With `fflush` I can get to a point `scanf()` is being executed, but the C program doesn't seem to see the output of Java, and the C program stops waiting for input on `scanf()` while the Java program waits on `readLine()`. So when I resolved one problem by `fflush()`, I have no idea why C by human input works correctly and wrong when Java executes it (also I don't know why `fflush()` is only needed when Java executes).

The problem simply is `scanf()` doesn't seem to see writes of Java.

Comment: Try `setvbuf` on `stdin`and `stdout` with the 2nd argument set to `_IONBF`

Comment: It helps to remove the need of fflush() and explains it why it may be needed but still doesn't seem to work with scanf()

Comment: My Java knowledge is a bit rusty so I'll have to ask, did you check if your Java program ever leaves the `while((val=reader.readLine())!=null)` loop?

Comment: Facepalmed, thanks. It works. After removing while and just set it to print it works right.